# How To scroll to the last message in the react virtualization message container

Tags: next.js, typescript2.0

I am using `scrollToIndex` and `scrollToRow` but is not working on adding a new message, Also I tried with use ref but was not able to make it work, feel free to suggest. In your text, I would be more than happy to receive.

I want to scroll to the last message when we add a new message.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 parentRef.current!?.lastElementChild?.scrollIntoView()
}, [messagesList])

const rowRenderer = useCallback(
 ({index, isScrolling, key, parent, style, scrollToRow}) => {
  const chat = messagesList[index]
  console.log(
   'cell renderer index : ',
   index,
   ' list length : ',
   messagesList.length
  )
  return (
   <CellMeasurer
    cache={cache}
    columnIndex={0}
    key={key}
    parent={parent}
    rowIndex={index}
    className='List'
    scrollToRow={messagesList.length - 1}
    autoHeight={true}
    autoWidth={true}
    // ref={parentRef}
    recomputeRowHeights={index}
    recomputeRowWidths={index}
    resetMeasurementForRow={index}
    resetMeasurementForColumn={index}
    resetMeasurements={true}
    style={{wordWrap: 'break-word', whiteSpace: 'normal', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
    {({measure, registerChild}: any) => (
     <div style={style}>
      <Message
       key={chat?.id}
       ref={registerChild}
       data={chat}
      />
     </div>
    )}
   </CellMeasurer>
  )
 },
 [messagesList, cache]
)

const getMessages = useMemo(() => {
 console.log('getting messages....')

 return (
  <List
   scrollToAlignment={'end'}
   height={700}
   width={wrapperRef.current ? wrapperRef.current?.clientWidth : 100}
   style={{width: '100%', border: '2px solid grey'}} // important to maintain the width
   itemSize={10}
   deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
   rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
   rowCount={messagesList.length}
   rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
   // scrollToIndex={messagesList.length}
   // ref={parentRef}
   scrollToRow={messagesList.length - 1}

   // scrollToIndex
  />
 )
}, [messagesList, wrapperRef.current])
```

Comment: Need some clarity in your question. Is your `messagesList` is a state ?  How you are calling `getMessages` ?

Comment: scrollToIndex={messagesList.length - 1} works fine here and this solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

`scrollToIndex={messagesList.length - 1}` works fine here and this solved my issue